# Merge join not working as documented Redshift

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift, sql-execution-plan

From AWS Documentation:
Merge Join

> Typically the fastest join, a merge join is used for inner joins and outer joins. The merge join is not used for full joins. **This operator is used when joining tables where the join columns are both distribution keys and sort keys, and when less than 20 percent of the joining tables are unsorted.** It reads two sorted tables in order and finds the matching rows. To view the percent of unsorted rows, query the SVV_TABLE_INFO system table.

The join I am testing:

```
select *  
FROM d2l.tbl1 r
JOIN d2l.tbl2 rc
ON r.sortkey1_field = rc.sortkey1_field
```

SVV_TABLE_INFO details:

[image: SVV_TABLE_INFO details]

Execution plan:

[image: Explan Plan]

I have full vacuumed and analyzed both table before running explain.

Also per AWS documentation distyle all should be have the same as two objects having the same distkey. Despite that I have recreated tables with distkey on the given join field and it was still not giving merge on explain plan.

Can someone explain what is going on or at least what would need to be changed to make this a merge join?

Comment: Why do you want a merge join? A hash join is typically faster

Comment: Per aws documentation Merge Join is the fastest join:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-the-query-plan.html

Merge Join Typically the fastest join (of three join operators in redshift nested, hash , merge) 

This join is a part of a much larger query and the current load runs occasionally up to two hours. I am looking for performance enhancements. Any tips on improving performance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any documentation/reasoning for why hash join would be faster?Current query has 16 joins 14 of them being inner joins.

Comment: The merge join needs so sort the data in order to work. That makes it slower unless the data can be retrieved in a sorted manner from the harddisk. See e.g. here: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/join/sort-merge-join

Comment: Both tables are already sorted on the join field

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Comment: Try changing diststyle all to diststyle even, does that make a difference?

Comment: I dont think having DISTSTYLE all for both the columns will give the expected result. Can you pls point me to the documentation ?.Merge plan comes out only when both dist and sort keys are the joining columns

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_explain_plan_example.html

Comment: Merge Joins are much faster than Hash Joins. However, depending on query predicates it can sometimes make sense to forgo the Merge Join if there is an effective SORT KEY that enables efficient range restricted scans.

Answer (score 2):

A merge join requires that both tables are distributed with DIST STYLE KEY with the same key. The first column of the SORT KEY on both tables must also be the same as the DIST KEY. Merge joins also require updated statistics/vacuum.

The reason it's not working in your case is that both your tables are distributed with DISTSTYLE ALL.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_explain_plan_example.html shows example using distyle all. If you read the comment you would know that the table was vacuumed and analyzed.

Comment: What I stated are all of the conditions required for a merge join to take place.
In the example on the docs - the MERGE JOIN takes place between the sales and the listing table which are both distributed and sorted by the same column.
XN Hash Join DS_DIST_ALL_NONE   <-- is the join (Hash) and the broadcast type for ALL tables
XN Merge Join DS_DIST_NONE   <-- is the join (Merge) and broadcast type in this case is no-redistribution because the data is co-located.